# Invariant curves of rational functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $\gamma$ be a Jordan analytic curve on the Riemann sphere, and $f$ a rational function 
of degree at least 2 which
maps $\gamma$ onto itself *homeomorphically*. The following examples of such situation are known:

a) $\gamma$ is a circle

b) $\gamma$ is a level curve of the linearizing map $\phi$ in a rotation domain. This means that there
is a simply or doubly connected region where $f$ is conjugate to an irrational rotation of a disc
or a ring:
$$\phi\circ f=\lambda\phi,$$
where $\lambda=\exp(\pi i\alpha)$, $\alpha$ irrational.

> Are there other examples? Can a rational function $f$ of degree at least $2$ map an
>   invariant Jordan analytic
>   curve, which intersects the Julia set $J(f)$, and which is not a circle,  homeomorphically?

If one drops the condition that $f:\gamma\to\gamma$ is a homeomorphism, there are examples
in http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6552 and in the answer of Peter Mueller to my previous question
[Circles and rational functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103949).